# rosrun does not appear to do anything. Node exits immediately

Tags: ros

I have a ROS node that seems to exit immediately or not even run at all. I have test print statements before the main loop and it never seems to get to that point. roscore is running and no error messages appear in the terminal window.

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <iostream>

#define ROS_LOOP_RATE 2000

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    std::cout << "TEST1\n";
    ros::init(argc, argv, "network_wdg_node");

    std::cout << "TEST2\n";
    ros::NodeHandle wdgNodeHandle("~");

    std::cout << "TEST3\n";
    ros::Rate loop_rate(ROS_LOOP_RATE);

    std::cout << "TEST4\n";

    while(ros::ok())
    {
        std::cout << "INSIDE LOOP\n";
        ros::spinOnce();
        loop_rate.sleep();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here's my terminal output:

```
[rosrun] Looking in catkin libexec dirs: 
/home/catkin_ws/devel/lib/test
/home/catkin_ws/devel/share/test
/home/catkin_ws/src/test
[rosrun] Looking in rospack dir: /home/catkin_ws/src/test
[rosrun] Searching for network_wdg_node with permissions /111
[rosrun] Running  /home/catkin_ws/devel/lib/network_wdg/test_node
```

I can't seem to figure out why the node doesn't start running or even get to the first debug statement.

Comment: Can you add your file structure? And maybe the relevant contents of your CMakeLists? And you're just running the node with rosrun? You could always run an `strace -p <pid>` on the process and see what it's doing, if anything.

Comment: I solved/figure out the issue. I was running "rosrun test_node test_node" when it was just building an executable named "node". It was my fault for not reading CMakeLists closely enough.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the ability to promote the [above comment](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/20166/rosrun-does-not-appear-to-do-anything-node-exits-immediately#comment33234_20166) where the OP confirms the answer:

> I solved/figure out the issue. I was running "rosrun test_node
> test_node" when it was just building an executable named "node". It
> was my fault for not reading CMakeLists closely enough